# Wrong pagination link count laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

I need to **skip** the first **n** records, say 5 from a table and paginate the rest of it. The following is the code that i am using.

```
$skipNewsListArr = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$wrongPaginationLinks = DB::table('news')
                        ->whereNotIn('news_id',$skipNewsListArr)
                        ->orderBy('news_date','desc')
                        ->paginate(5);
```

But the above code outputs the pagination links corresponding to the whole table. How can i achieve pagination by skipping records based on some condition.

Comment: try to use `DB::table('news')->skip(5)->orderBy('news_date','desc')->paginate(5);`

Comment: @SafoorSafdar won't that ignore the 5 newest news items plus any in the ignored array? ie. the `skip` will affect the query results as well as the pagination

Comment: all right, you just want to skip first 5 from all record and then paginate it? right?

Comment: Sorry For the wrong question the code is working fine.. and no need of skip. The last page number had only one result and due to some animation script the result was not showing... I sincierly apologize for the waste of time... if any moderators see this question please mark it as closed..

Comment: @SafoorSafdar Thanks for your quick help. I apologize for any inconvenience caused..